# passing custom object to another ps1 script

Tags: powershell

I'd like to pass a custom made object from script to another.

Beginning of subscript.ps1 there are input parameters:

```
param(
  [string]$someString,
  [object]$custClassData
 )
```

In the main.ps1 I'm trying to call the subscript.ps1 after introducing a custom object:

```
class custClass{
   [string]$string1
   [string]$string2
   [string]$string3
}

$customizedObject = [custClass]::new()
$customizedObject.string1 = "smthng1"
$customizedObject.string2 = "smthng2"
$customizedObject.string3 = "smthng3"
$scriptPath = ".\subscript.ps1"
$smString = "somethingsomething"
powershell.exe -file $scriptPath -someString $smString -custClassData $customizedObject
```

When calling like this if i check in subscript $custClassData.GetType it returns System.String, so i only get the name of the object there. If I generate class and object in the powershell manually and put data there and pass it to the subscript the type is custClass.

Comment: You can not pass live object into new PowerShell.exe process. Command line arguments for native executables are strings and can not be anything else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In *subscript.ps1* the `$custClassData` parameter needs to validate the type `[CustClass]` not `[object]`.  So something like:

```
param(
  [string]$someString,
  [CustClass]$custClassData
 )
```

This way the data that is passed to that parameter must be of the type `[CustClass]`.

Additionally, the way you are calling *subscript.ps1* does not look correct. You do not need to call `powershell.exe` in order to invoke *subscript.ps1*. `powershell.exe` will always throw an error here.

You should change *subscript.ps1* to *subscript.psm1*, and turn the contents of the script into a function, and use it like this:

**In subscript.psm1**:

```
function Do-TheNeedful {
    param(
      [string]$someString,
      [CustClass]$custClassData
    )
    #~
    # do work
    #~
}
```

**In main.ps1**

```
class custClass{
   [string]$string1
   [string]$string2
   [string]$string3
}

Import-Module subscript.psm1

$customizedObject = [custClass]::new()
$customizedObject.string1 = "smthng1"
$customizedObject.string2 = "smthng2"
$customizedObject.string3 = "smthng3"
Do-TheNeedful -someString "a_string" -custClassData $customizedObject
```

Comment: Ended up having subscript as dot sourced and moving functionality to a function.
`. .\subscript.ps1`
`Do-TheNeedful -someString "xy" -custClassData $customizedObject`

Comment: Beautiful solution! Solid thinking on that. Good stuff, @Pekafu

Answer (score 1):

Calling `powershell.exe` casts everything to strings. Launch the script file directly instead:

File: `sub.ps1`

```
param(
  [object]$foo
)

$foo
```

File: `main.ps1`

```
class myClass{
    [string]$A
}

$myObject = [myClass]::new()
$myObject.A = "BAR"

.\sub.ps1 $myObject
```